# Method that outputs every vowel from string once

Tags: java

My current code outputs only the first vowel it encounters.
I'd like to know a way to output every vowel that is inputed once.

```
public static String vowels(String str) {
    
String vowels = "auioeëyAUIOEËY";
    
for(int i = 0;i < str.length();i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j < str.length();j++) {
            
if(str.charAt(i) == vowels.charAt(j)) {
                return "cointains " + vowels.charAt(j) ;
            }
        }   
    }
    return "none";
}
```

Comment: The first time you find a match, you execute this line: `return "cointains " + vowels.charAt(j)` which exits from the function.  If you want to keep going, then do something at that line that does not cause the function to exit.

Comment: For your second loop, I think you want `j < vowels.length()` rather than `j < str.length()`.

Comment: Please format you code with correct indentation, it makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Your inner loop should be using `vowels.length()` (not `str.length()`). You need to continue iterating and gathering the matches if you don't want to return the first vowel. You might use a `Set`. Something like,

```
public static String vowels(String str) {
    String vowels = "auioeëyAUIOEËY";
    Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < vowels.length(); j++) {
            if (vowels.charAt(j) == ch) {
                charSet.add(ch);
            }
        }
    }
    if (charSet.isEmpty()) {
        return "none";
    }
    return "contains " + charSet.stream().map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```